# Is there a way to find all unbound steps in SpecFlow?

Tags: specflow

**My case is this:** I refactor some test steps and I wanna make sure after my refactoring is done all old tests steps are changed to new ones.

So I need to make sure my project doesn't have unbound steps. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Specflow has a 'stepdefinitionreport' command which you can use to generate a HTML report which shows which steps are used / unused.

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport MySpecflowProject.csproj /BinFolder:bin/debug
```

MySpecflowProject.csproj is your project, BinFolder: is the output directory where the report will be made.

Comment: Where can I take this specflow.exe file?

Comment: For me it is located in <path to solution>\packages\SpecFlow.2.4.0

Comment: Thanks. It needed more investigation before using (parameters are a little bit different here) but it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: There is no SpecFlow.exe on my current version of SpecFlow: 3.1.74. This must be a legacy feature

Answer (score 0):

I use a unit test coverage tool (such as dotcover) to highlight used steps (green). 
This show unused steps as grey for easy removal.